# Типы данных в PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, postgresql

До этого делал БД на СУБД MySQl, решил освоить PostgreSQL, и увидел что нету тех типов данных, которые есть в MySQL.

Например: TINYINT, CHAR, VARCHAR... еще нету команды UNSIGNED

Есть ли альтернатива этому в PostgreSQL? И как быть с UNSIGNED числами?

По умолчанию в PostgreSQL INT от -2 147 483 648 до +2 147 483 647, как и в MySQL.
Но, в MySQL можно расширить в большую сторону 0 до 4 294 967 295, и число по прежнему будет занимать 4 байта.

2 147 483 647 записей это уже 8.5 гигабайт, и это только один столбец.
4 294 967 295 записей в MySQL будут весить 17 гигабайт, а в PostgreSQL будут весить в два раз больше? Пролейте свет на эту ситуацию.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Модификатора `unsigned` и однобайтного числа `tinyint` в postgresql действительно нет.

Char и varchar [вполне себе есть.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-character.html)

> 2 147 483 647 записей это уже 8.5 гигабайт, и это только один столбец. 4 294 967 295 записей в MySQL будут весить 17 гигабайт, а в PostgreSQL будут весить в два раз больше?

Если говорить о дисковом размере рабочей таблицы - зависит от структуры таблицы и, возможно неожиданно, от профиля использования таблицы, точного её определения и даже порядка полей в таблице. Аналогичную ремарку, к слову, заслуживает и mysql, но зависит в первую очередь от storage engine и деталей реализации именно этого engine.

Если говорить про сырые данные - если вам нужен диапазон по меньшей мере `unsigned int` в 32 бита - то минимальный подходящий тип данных в postgresql - это 64-битный bigint. Значит для хранения 4млрд значений будет 4млрд * 8 байт, то есть около 32гб сырых данных.

Comment: а я нашел информацию, что в PostgreSQL можно создавать типы? но не нашел информации как создать такие как в MySQL...

Comment: В мануале есть пример: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xtypes.html Затем к этому прикрутить поддержку сбора статистики, операторов и классов операторов для индексирования, за основу можно взять штатные числовые типы. И в итоге завернуть в `extension`. То есть да, при большом желании можно реализовать любые типы и любую логику для них и работать они будут неотличимо от встроенных. Мне пока не попадались usecase, где спасает бит знака - или табличка растёт достаточно быстро чтобы упереться в int32 и всё равно bigint делать или 2млрд значений достаточно.

Comment: если же нужно только правильное имя для типа (возможно с дополнительными check) используя другой тип как базовый - то вам нужен `create domain` https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createdomain.html

Comment: Жаль, что PostgreSQL нету такого чуда как UNSIGNED, для увеличения диапазона(((

Comment: нашел, кое чего интересное - https://github.com/petere/pguint
Правда непонятно, как установить?

Comment: Действительно, как накатить это чудо https://github.com/petere/pguint
из инструкции автора по установке ничего неясно,что куда нужно заткнуть, что бы оно работало?)

Comment: Сделать типичные make && make install и дёрнуть не менее стандартный create extension в нужной базе - на мой взгляд всё описано. Если есть конкретные проблемы - то лучше отдельным вопросом.

Comment: "Сделать типичные make && make install" а как и где, и куда єто потом запихнуть?